# Вставить элемент в любое место документа

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая добавляет данные в конец документа. Как сделать так, что бы данные добавлялись в середину документа/в любое место.

```
  async function getDataFromCnbc() {

    const response = await fetch("https://corsproxy.glitch.me/https://www.cnbc.com/id/10000664/device/rss/rss.html");
    const xml = await response.text();
    const xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

    for(const node of xmlDocument.querySelectorAll("item")) {
        const details = document.createElement("details");
        const summary = document.createElement("summary");
        summary.append(node.querySelector("title"));        
        const description = document.createElement("description");
        description.innerHTML = node.querySelector("description").textContent;        
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = node.querySelector("link").textContent;
        link.textContent = "Read more";  
        details.append(summary, description, link);
        document.body.append(details);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getDataFromCnbc);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: что значит любое? посреди строки тоже любое. как это можно определить

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Получаете элемент по его идентификатору
let div = document.getElementById('element_id');

// Создаёте новый элемент '<span>'
let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.textContent = 'Content';

// Добавляете созданный элемент в конец родительского
div.appendChild(newSpan);
```

[Подробная информация в документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: это не совсем то что нужно автору...

Comment: спс разобралса )))